# How do you close the terminal in an NPM script in the package.json for Windows?

Tags: windows, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

In my **package.json**, I have scripts that open in new terminals using "start" (Windows OS only):

```
"automation": "start npm run webdriver:start && npm run timeout"
"webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start",
"timeout": "timeout 3",
```

My question is how do I then close that terminal window once the action is complete?

I have tried the following but neither **close** the terminal window:

```
"automation": "(start npm run webdriver:start && npm run timeout) && exit"
"automation": "(start npm run webdriver:start && npm run timeout) && exit 1"
```

When I do just an "exit" in a Windows terminal, it does close the window but it doesn't seem to work in the script. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Running the following command:

```
npm run automation
```

Comment: Try this: `cmd.exe /c "npm run webdriver:start && npm run timeout"` cmd.exe is a Windows command-line shell, from the help: /C Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

Comment: Is that for powershell? I'm not running in powershell.
Also that will not work outside of the string as the syntax for package.json will not allow that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637481/126995

Comment: Still not sure what you're getting at. In the scripts in the package.json I cannot put `cmd.exe /c` outside of the string. And I'm not sure how three slashes will help. Can you give me the exact example of how to write it for package.json format?

Comment: You need to escape the quotes like this: "automation": "cmd /c \"(start npm run webdriver:start && npm run timeout) && exit\"", however i've tried @Soonts answer and i didn't manage to get it work from vscode

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946868/how-to-get-rid-of-terminal-will-be-reused-by-tasks-press-any-key-to-close-it

Answer (score 0):

VSCode doesn't allows to close the terminal from the script (check [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35642)), how ever you can just "silence" the newly open terminal, for that you'll have to modify your `tasks.json` file by adding the `reveal`, `clear` and `showReuseMessage` to it.

Your `tasks.json` file should end up to something like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "automation",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
              "reveal": "silent",
              "clear": true,
              "showReuseMessage": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you'r `task.json` file is missing check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268034/where-is-the-tasks-json-file-in-vscode).