# How to close the task terminal automatically after vscode debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

launch.json

```json
...
"preLaunchTask": "startDebug",
"postDebugTask": "closeOpenOCDTerminal"
```

tasks.json

```json
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "startDebug",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make -j4; openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -c 'transport select swd' -f target/stm32f1x.cfg",
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": {
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "."
            },
            "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": ".",
                "endsPattern": "."
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "closeOpenOCDTerminal",
        "type": "process",
        "command":[
            "${command:workbench.action.tasks.terminate}",
            // "${command:workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem}" //invalid
         ]
    }
]
}
```

The OpenOCD service does not end automatically like the make command, only depends on closing the terminal or executing Ctrl + C.
How to automatically close the task terminal after debugging？
Or execute Ctrl + C command automatically in the task terminal to end the Openocd service.
The currently used closeOpenOCDTerminal method requires manual clicking on the pop-up list.

Comment: Is your `startDebug` in launch.json or tasks.json?  Shouldn't it be in launch.json?

Answer (score 6):

The tasks.json file in VSCode (1.57) now has a property called `close` in the `presentation` property. And you can use it to close the terminal.

> ### [Automatically close task terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_automatically-close-task-terminals)
>
> The task `presentation` property has a new `close` property.
> **Setting `close` to `true` will cause the terminal to close when the task exits.**
>
> ```json
> {
>   "type": "shell",
>   "command": "node build/lib/preLaunch.js",
>   "label": "Ensure Prelaunch Dependencies",
>   "presentation": {
>       "reveal": "silent",
>       "close": true
>   }
> }
> ```

### TIP

Note that it is recommended to switch to the "Problems" tab in the terminal after using the close option - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67872135/6908282)

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make -j4; openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -c 'transport select swd' -f target/stm32f1x.cfg",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "."
                },
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": ".",
                    "endsPattern": "."
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "stop",
            "command": "echo ${input:terminate}",
            "type": "shell",
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "terminate",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate",
          "args": "terminateAll"
        }
    ]
}
```

This example happens to close the task terminal.